# while reading hbase table with bigtable-hbase-1.x.-hadoop.1.12.0, it get stuck

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, google-cloud-bigtable

when I read the HBase table using bigtable-hbase-1.x.-hadoop.1.12.0 jar it got stuck, does not show any error/exception log.
Also, check with the latest version of bigtable-hbase-1.x.-hadoop.1.26.1, giving the same behavior.
Prior to this bigtable-hbase-1.x-hadoop-1.12.0 version,all versions are working

Using below HBase jar

1. hbase-annotations-1.1.2.2.6.1.0-129.jar
2. hbase-client-1.1.2.2.6.1.0-129.jar
3. hbase-common-1.1.2.2.6.1.0-129.jar
4. hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.6.1.0-129.jar
5. hbase-common-1.1.2.2.6.1.0-129-tests.jar

below is the piece of code

```
public  HashMap<String, Object> readById(String id) {
    Table table = getConnection().getTable("Table Name");
    Get getOp1 = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(id));
    Result result = table.get(getOp1);
 }
```

get stuck at table.get(getOp1);
Same code working on local but getting stuck after deploying it on  GCP instance.
Anyone can help on this?

Comment: Did the HBase log tell you anything?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am able to resolve the issue. There is one method that is not present in a Scan class(from HDP HBase-client jar). So I removed all the above HBase jar from the HDP repo, added only the hbase-client shaded jar. This hbase-client shaded jar has thie method.

Comment: Could you post that as the answer and mark it correct?  Adding a comment isn't as helpful as posting what the answer is.